# Tensorflow - Unable to use a BasicLSTMCell with a MirroredStrategy distribution in Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell` as part of my NN architecture. I use a for loop because it is recursing over input a fixed number of time steps. Something like this:

```
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=lstm_dimensionality, name="forward_lstm")
    _, (lstm_memory, lstm_hidden) = lstm_cell(input_m, state=[lstm_memory, lstm_hidden])

    for i in range(3):
        # HERE is where the error is thrown
        _, (lstm_memory, lstm_hidden) = lstm_cell(input_m, state=[lstm_memory, lstm_hidden])
```

It works quite well locally on a single device. It also works fine in Google ML Engine on a single GPU. However, when I try distributing to 4 GPUs using `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`, it throws an exception

```
ValueError: At least one of name (None) and default_name (None) must be provided.
```

The `lstm_cell` callable doesn't even take a `name` parameter so it's confusing.

There isn't much room for details here, so I've created a toy example in this [Github repo](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro) to reproduce the bug in ML Engine. It is specifically on [this line](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro/blob/master/trainer/model.py#L54) where the error is thrown.

Tensorflow: `1.13.1`
ML Engine: `--runtime-version 1.13`

Comment: I'm not expert in Tensorflow scope. However, [here](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro/blob/4008c2f0c1f6fdc14cc6ac6194886de867f63542/trainer/model.py#L48) you use a scope in the function `compute_initial_lstm_state`. The you reuse the 2 returned value [here](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro/blob/4008c2f0c1f6fdc14cc6ac6194886de867f63542/trainer/model.py#L54). You use a scope to generate values and you assign them without scope. I don't know if it's the root error, but with a single GPU, the scope can be deduce, on multi gpu not. It's just an idea.

Comment: You are right! I just needed to wrap things in `tf.variable_scope`. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code [here](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro/blob/4008c2f0c1f6fdc14cc6ac6194886de867f63542/trainer/model.py#L48) you use a scope in the function `compute_initial_lstm_state`.

The you reuse the 2 returned values [here](https://github.com/onehotio/bug-repro/blob/4008c2f0c1f6fdc14cc6ac6194886de867f63542/trainer/model.py#L54)

You use a scope to generate values and you assign them without scope.

This should be your root error. With a single GPU, the scope can be deduce automatically. But with multi gpu, it's not possible and it fail.